# How to remove symbols from beginning and end of a string, except certain symbols?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am currently using this regex:

```
/^[^a-z\d]*|[^a-z\d]*$/gi
```

This checks for a symbol in the beginning and end of a string.

However, I want to exclude these 4 symbols from being removed:

```
(
)
[
]
```

How can I modify my regex so that it doesn't remove those symbols?

Comment: Just add them to the character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you can add them to the excludes list:

```
/^[^\(\[\)\]a-z\d]*|[^\(\[\)\]a-z\d]*$/gi
```

(if I understand correctly and you want to remove all symbols up to the first occurence of one of these symbols - if not, this will not be a single regex, I think)

Comment: There is no need to escape the `()[` in the character class (which makes the expression a but more readable).

Comment: @FelixKling: Okay, I didn't know this. For my personal uses I'd prefer escaping them though, since if I look somewhere into the regex, I can see at first sight, that these symbols don't have syntactical flavour.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MKjb3/2/)

It can remove all the special characters include `()[]`

```
var test = "([xxxx &dagger; yyyy &sect; zzzz)]";
alert(test.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, ''));
```

Comment: This will replace those characters **anywhere** in the string, not at beginning and end...